# Pandas - possible to aggregate two columns using two different aggregations?

Tags: pandas, aggregation

I'm loading a csv file, which has the following columns:
date, textA, textB, numberA, numberB

I want to group by the columns: date, textA and textB - but want to apply "sum" to numberA, but "min" to numberB.

```
data = pd.read_table("file.csv", sep=",", thousands=',')
grouped = data.groupby(["date", "textA", "textB"], as_index=False)
```

...but I cannot see how to then apply two different aggregate functions, to two different columns?
I.e. `sum(numberA), min(numberB)`

Comment: This is an old question. Please refer to 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374620/python-pandas-applying-different-aggregate-functions-to-different-columns

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `agg` method can accept a dict, in which case the keys indicate the column to which the function is applied:

```
grouped.agg({'numberA':'sum', 'numberB':'min'})
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                         'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                         'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                   'number A': np.arange(8),
                   'number B': np.arange(8) * 2})
grouped = df.groupby('A')

print(grouped.agg({
    'number A': 'sum',
    'number B': 'min'}))
```

yields

```
     number B  number A
A                      
bar         2         9
foo         0        19
```

This also shows that Pandas can handle spaces in column names. I'm not sure what the origin of the problem was, but literal spaces should not have posed a problem. If you wish to investigate this further,

```
print(df.columns)
```

*without reassigning the column names*, will show show us the `repr` of the names. Maybe there was a hard-to-see character in the column name that looked like a space (or some other character) but was actually a `u'\xa0'` (NO-BREAK SPACE), for example.

Comment: thanks - for the quick response. I had tried this, but I get a "KeyError: u'no item named KeyError: u'no item named Number A '"

Maybe that's related to my column name having a space in?
I'll experiment to see if that makes a difference

Comment: Woah, you can also do stuff like this: `g.agg({'A': ['min', 'max'], 'B': 'mean'})`

Comment: Just added a "names" param to read_table, and renamed all my columns by removing any spaces in the column names. That did the trick - the method I had previously tried (and Andy suggested) now works.

Comment: @marcusadamski this should work fine with spaces in the columns names.