# python pandas: applying different aggregate functions to different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to understand what the equivalent of this simple SQL statement would be:

```
select mykey, sum(Field1) as sum_of_field1, avg(Field1) as avg_field1, min(field2) as min_field2
from df
group by mykey
```

I understand I can passa a dictionary to the agg() function:

```
  f = {'Field1':'sum',
         'Field2':['max','mean'],
         'Field3':['min','mean','count'],
         'Field4':'count'
         }

    grouped = df.groupby('mykey').agg(f)
```

However, the resulting column names seem to be chosen by pandas automatically: `('Field1','sum')` etc.

Is there a way to pass strings for column names, so that the field is not `('Field1','sum')` but something I can choose, like sum_of_field1 ?

Thanks. I looked at the docs here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html
but couldn't quite find an answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As of pandas 0.25, this is possible with a ["Named aggregation"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation).

```
In [79]: animals = pd.DataFrame({'kind': ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog'],
   ....:                         'height': [9.1, 6.0, 9.5, 34.0],
   ....:                         'weight': [7.9, 7.5, 9.9, 198.0]})
   ....: 

In [80]: animals
Out[80]: 
  kind  height  weight
0  cat     9.1     7.9
1  dog     6.0     7.5
2  cat     9.5     9.9
3  dog    34.0   198.0

In [82]: animals.groupby("kind").agg(
   ....:     min_height=('height', 'min'),
   ....:     max_height=('height', 'max'),
   ....:     average_weight=('weight', np.mean),
   ....: )
   ....: 
Out[82]: 
      min_height  max_height  average_weight
kind                                        
cat          9.1         9.5            8.90
dog          6.0        34.0          102.75
```

The previously deprecated version follows:

---

You can pass a dictionary of dictionaries to `.agg` mapping `{column: {name: aggfunc}}`, for example

```
In [46]: df.head()
Out[46]:
   Year  qtr  realgdp  realcons  realinvs  realgovt  realdpi  cpi_u      M1  \
0  1950    1   1610.5    1058.9     198.1     361.0   1186.1   70.6  110.20
1  1950    2   1658.8    1075.9     220.4     366.4   1178.1   71.4  111.75
2  1950    3   1723.0    1131.0     239.7     359.6   1196.5   73.2  112.95
3  1950    4   1753.9    1097.6     271.8     382.5   1210.0   74.9  113.93
4  1951    1   1773.5    1122.8     242.9     421.9   1207.9   77.3  115.08

   tbilrate  unemp      pop     infl  realint
0      1.12    6.4  149.461   0.0000   0.0000
1      1.17    5.6  150.260   4.5071  -3.3404
2      1.23    4.6  151.064   9.9590  -8.7290
3      1.35    4.2  151.871   9.1834  -7.8301
4      1.40    3.5  152.393  12.6160 -11.2160

In [47]: df.groupby('qtr').agg({"realgdp": {"mean_gdp": "mean", "std_gdp": "std"},
                                "unemp": {"mean_unemp": "mean"}})
Out[47]:
         realgdp                   unemp
        mean_gdp      std_gdp mean_unemp
qtr
1    4506.439216  2104.195963   5.694118
2    4546.043137  2121.824090   5.686275
3    4580.507843  2132.897955   5.662745
4    4617.592157  2158.132698   5.654902
```

The result has a MultiIndex in the columns. If you don't want that outer level, you can use `.columns.droplevel(0)`.

Comment: Thanks! Super useful! You should have this added to the official documentation (unless it's already there and I failed to find it)

Comment: It's not in the docs, but there's an issue to document it correctly here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9052 A pull-request adding it would be great, if you're up for it!

Comment: This is no longer possible. Python now produces a warning that "using a dict with renaming is deprecated and will be removed in a future version". Why, oh, please someone explain why!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I agree this is a bit frustrating butI do find chaining with a `rename` method served my purpose. Also, when it gets really complex, I will just reset the column names. It is a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) so it is immutable, and you should feel comfortable dealing with levels.

Based on the pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once)

> The resulting aggregations are named for the functions themselves. If
>   you need to rename, then you can add in a chained operation for a
>   Series like this

```
In [67]: (grouped['C'].agg([np.sum, np.mean, np.std])
   ....:              .rename(columns={'sum': 'foo',
   ....:                               'mean': 'bar',
   ....:                               'std': 'baz'})
   ....: )
   ....: 
Out[67]: 
          foo       bar       baz
A                                
bar  0.392940  0.130980  0.181231
foo -1.796421 -0.359284  0.912265
```

When there are multiples uses of one function and you want to name it differently, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895292/how-do-you-rename-all-columns-in-multi-level-group-by-in-pandas-0-20-1) of dropping the level and joining the different levels by underscore will help.

If you do find the sql syntax cleaner, there is a library called [pandasql](https://github.com/yhat/pandasql) that give you this flexibility.