# How do you rename all columns in multi level group by in pandas 0.20.1+

Tags: python, pandas

With the release of Pandas 0.20.1, there is a new deprecation of the functionality to groupby.agg() with a dictionary for renaming.

[Deprecation documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-groupby-agg-with-a-dictionary-when-renaming)

I'm trying to find best way to update my code to account for this, however I'm struggling with how I've currently been utilizing this rename functionality.

When I am doing an aggregate, I often have multiple functions for each source column, and I have been using this rename functionality to get to a single level index with these new column names.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],'B': range(5),'C': range(5)})

In [30]: df
Out[30]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  0  0
1  1  1  1
2  1  2  2
3  2  3  3
4  2  4  4

frame = df.groupby('A').agg({'B' : {'foo':'sum'}, 'C': {'bar' : 'min', 'bar2': 'max'}})
```

Which results in:

```
Out[33]: 
    B   C     
  foo bar bar2
A             
1   3   0    2
2   7   3    4
```

Which I then typically do:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(frame).reset_index(col_level=1)

frame.columns = frame.columns.get_level_values(1)

frame
Out[42]: 
   A  foo  bar  bar2
0  1    3    0     2
1  2    7    3     4
```

So I'm looking for good ways to get a result dataframe that is single level index, but has new unique column names. Where multiple columns originated from an aggregate from a single source column.  Any recommendations of best approach is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This works perfectly in `0.20.1` version:

```
d = {'sum':'foo','min':'bar','max':'bar2'}
frame = df.groupby('A').agg({'B' : ['sum'], 'C': ['min', 'max']}).rename(columns=d)
frame.columns = frame.columns.droplevel(0)
frame = frame.reset_index()
print (frame)
   A  foo  bar  bar2
0  1    3    0     2
1  2    7    3     4
```

If multiple `min`s:

```
d = {'B_sum':'foo','C_min':'bar','C_max':'bar2'}
frame = df.groupby('A').agg({'B' : ['sum'], 'C': ['min', 'max']})
frame.columns = frame.columns.map('_'.join)
frame = frame.reset_index().rename(columns=d)
print (frame)
   A  foo  bar  bar2
0  1    3    0     2
1  2    7    3     4
```

Comment: Thank you, overall I think I can work with that.  Only challenge I have is if similar or same agg function is used more than once.  I often use lambda functions across my columns.  Simple example though would be if I added:
'B' : ['sum','min']  and then had two columns as 'min'.

Comment: Yes, then need first create `Index` with `Multiindex`, simplier solution is with `map`. Check edited answer.

Comment: Perfect. Makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for your usual contribution to pandas related question. It introduced a new function `droplevel` to me

Answer (score 7):

Here is bit shorter alternative:

```
In [78]: d={'C_min':'min_C', 'C_sum':'sum_C','B_min':'min_B','B_sum':'sum_B'}

In [79]: frame
Out[79]:
    C       B
  min sum min sum
A
1   0   3   0   3
2   3   7   3   7

In [80]: frame.columns = frame.columns.map('_'.join).to_series().map(d)

In [81]: frame
Out[81]:
   min_C  sum_C  min_B  sum_B
A
1      0      3      0      3
2      3      7      3      7
```

Comment: Instead of having to type out the mapping `d` manually, use `.swaplevel()` instead. Thus, the whole thing would look `frame.columns.swaplevel().map('_'.join)`

Answer (score 0):

You could just call `droplevel` on the columns and then `reset_index`:

```
In [46]:
frame.columns = frame.columns.droplevel(0)
frame = frame.reset_index()
frame

Out[46]:
   A  bar  bar2  foo
0  1    0     2    3
1  2    3     4    7
```

Comment: As in Pandas 0.23.4, `np.columns.droplevel()` is no longer available.