# pandas groupby: how to calculate percentage of total?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I calculate a column showing the % of total in a `groupby`?

One way to do it is to calculate it manually after the `groupby`, as in the last line of this example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5,8,(10,4)), columns=['a','b','c','d'])
g = df.groupby('a').agg({'b':['sum','mean'], 'c':['sum'], 'd':['sum']})
g.columns = g.columns.map('_'.join)
g['b %']=g['b_sum']/g['b_sum'].sum()
```

However, in my real data I have many more columns, and I'd need the % right after the `sum`, so with this approach I'd have to manually change the order of the columns.

Is there a more direct way of doing it so that the % is the column right after the `sum`? Note that I need the `agg()`, or something equivalent, because in all my `groupby`s I apply different aggregate functions to different columns (e.g. `sum` and `avg` of x, but only the min of y, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `lambda function` in [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) column names to `%`:

```
np.random.seed(78)
df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5,8,(10,4)), columns=['a','b','c','d'])

g =(df.groupby('a')
      .agg({'b':['sum',lambda x: x.sum()/ df['b'].sum(),'mean'],
            'c':['sum'], 
            'd':['sum']}))
g.columns = g.columns.map('_'.join).str.replace('<lambda>','%')

print (g)

   d_sum  c_sum  b_sum       b_%  b_mean
a                                       
5     25     24     24  0.387097       6
6     11     11     14  0.225806       7
7     22     23     24  0.387097       6
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I use a lambda function to calculate a weighted average in the groupby, too?

Comment: Hmm, do you need implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26205922/2901002) solution to `agg` ?

Comment: I see you replace lambda with % in the column names. But what if I have multiple lambda functions for the same column? E.g. for column b I may do sum(b) and %, then count(b) and related %. How could I rename the columns now that, for reasons honestly beyond me, using a nested dictionary for renaming is deprecated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694207/applying-different-aggregate-functions-to-different-columns-now-that-dict-with

Comment: Yes, it is not so easy. need replace not substring, but all columns like `g.columns = g.columns.map('_'.join)` and then `g = g.rename(columns={'b_<lambda>':'b _%'})`

Comment: yes, implementing the solution you linked to agg would be great! Do you know a way?

Comment: I think it is not possible. because need transform :(

Comment: Thank you for accepting, can you accept this solution too?