# Pyhon - Pandas, is it possibleto group rows where a column cell equals a specific value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two rows that look like

```
CustomerID, CustomerName, ValA, ValB, ValC, Vald
1899, CustomerBlue, 2, 5, 8, 9
1899B, CustomerBlue, 3, 6, 7, 8
```

I want to combine the rows to become;

```
1899, CustomerBlue, 5, 11, 15, 17
```

I started with this;

```
df.groupby(['CustomerName'], as_index=False).agg('sum')
```

But obviously that won't work because two columns are strings. Is there a way to replace the first two cells with what I want, and sum the rest?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pandas: applying different aggregate functions to different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374620/python-pandas-applying-different-aggregate-functions-to-different-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby_agg` with a dict mapping. Unfortunately, there is no default function to apply. You have to enumerate all columns...

```
>>> (df.groupby('CustomerName', as_index=False)
       .agg({'CustomerID': 'first', 'ValA': 'sum', 'ValB': 'sum',
             'ValC': 'sum', 'Vald': 'sum'}))

   CustomerName CustomerID  ValA  ValB  ValC  Vald
0  CustomerBlue       1899     5    11    15    17
```

Comment: Close. I used this. https://www.statology.org/pandas-combine-rows-with-same-column-value/

Comment: This is the same method :-)

Comment: It is - slightly tweaked. It's why I accepted your answer. Thanks!