# how to find the sum and average of multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 4 columns . The dataframe looks like this:

```
      date  sell price      cost price            discount
2019-10-13    2000            2000               0
2019-10-21    3000            3000               0
```

I need to find the total sum and average of 2 columns *cost price* and *sell price*. The output should be like:

```
                total      avg           
sell price       5000      2500          
cost price       5000      2500
```

How can I get this?

Comment: try `df['sell price'].sum()` and `df['sell price'].mean()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas - possible to aggregate two columns using two different aggregations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837659/pandas-possible-to-aggregate-two-columns-using-two-different-aggregations)

Answer (score 1):

Use `DataFrame.agg`:

```
  new_df=df[['sell_price', 'cost_price']].agg(['sum','mean']).T.rename(columns={'sum':'total','mean':'Avg'})
print(new_df)
```

---

```
             total     Avg
sell_price  5000.0  2500.0
cost_price  5000.0  2500.0
```

Comment: Please check now

Answer (score 0):

Use of aggregate should do this.

```
df.aggregate({"cost_price":['sum','mean'],"sell_price":['sum','mean']})
```

[update] why it does not work? Any error to see?
[image: img]